# Decorator pattern using Java 8

Tags: java, design-patterns, functional-programming

Wikipedia has an example of a decorator pattern here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Second_example_.28coffee_making_scenario.29

I was trying to solve this using functional style using Java 8 just to compare the Oop style and functional style of solving the same problem.

The solution I came up:

1.CoffeeDecorator.java

```
public class CoffeeDecorator {

public static Coffee getCoffee(Coffee basicCoffee, Function<Coffee, Coffee>... coffeeIngredients) {

    Function<Coffee, Coffee> chainOfFunctions = Stream.of(coffeeIngredients)
                                                      .reduce(Function.identity(),Function::andThen);
    return chainOfFunctions.apply(basicCoffee);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Coffee simpleCoffee = new SimpleCoffee();
    printInfo(simpleCoffee);

    Coffee coffeeWithMilk = CoffeeDecorator.getCoffee(simpleCoffee, CoffeeIngredient::withMilk);
    printInfo(coffeeWithMilk);

    Coffee coffeeWithWSprinkle = CoffeeDecorator.getCoffee(coffeeWithMilk,CoffeeIngredient::withSprinkles);     
    printInfo(coffeeWithWSprinkle);

}

public static void printInfo(Coffee c) {
    System.out.println("Cost: " + c.getCost() + "; Ingredients: " + c.getIngredients());
}
```

}

2.CoffeeIngredient.java

```
public class CoffeeIngredient { 

public static Coffee withMilk(Coffee coffee) {
    return new Coffee() {

        @Override
        public double getCost() {
            return coffee.getCost() + 0.5;
        }

        @Override
        public String getIngredients() {
            return coffee.getIngredients() + " , Milk";
        }
    };
}

public static Coffee withSprinkles(Coffee coffee) {
    return new Coffee() {

        @Override
        public double getCost() {
            return coffee.getCost() + 0.2;
        }

        @Override
        public String getIngredients() {
            return coffee.getIngredients() + " , Sprinkles";
        }
    };
}
```

}

Now, I am not so convinced with the solution in the CoffeeIngredient. If we had a single responsibility in the Coffee interface, getCost(), using the functional style and applying the decorator pattern seems a lot better and cleaner. It would basically boil down to a Function ,we would not need the abstract class, separate decorators and can just chain the functions.

But in the coffee example, with 2 behaviors of the cost and description on the Coffee interface, I am not so convinced that this is a significant value addition as we are creating an anonymous class,overriding the 2 methods.I am not looking at a performance perspective but rather looking at it from a functional vs oop style of solving the problem.

If we were to restrict our solution to functional design/style using Java 8, then :

Questions:

1) Is this functional style of solution acceptable ?

2) If not, is there a better way to solve it using Java 8 functional style rather than creating the anonymous classes which seem to implement Coffee interface ?

Comment: `Is this solution acceptable?` What does the specification say? Without specification, that's highly subjective.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because you're 1) talking about abstracts to later apply them to some situation you haven't shown us, which is a good way to shoot yourself in the foot. 2) You're changing the requirements halfway through the question, complicating everything and making answering impossible (if Coffee suddenly has different methods, then, yes, patterns might be too much! But if you can change the domain model by that much, then you're NOT following business requirements, are you?)

Comment: Now, I see that you have changed the calling code to be functional style. If you want us to review that, sure, we can do that. In that case, you should provide a clear set of requirements (to help restrict the "what-if"'s, preventing the question from becoming too broad), after which we can talk about what impacts your choices have on performance and future extend-ability of the coffee combinations.

Comment: I am only trying to solve the same problem mentioned on wiki in Java 8 functional style, I have mentioned that in my original description. So the first question of my solution being acceptable is assuming there are only 2 methods in the Coffee interface but the 3rd question is pretty much if the functional style loses value once there are multiple methods on the object being decorated.

Comment: @AjayIyengar without proper restrictions, this question is too broad. The answer I'd give right now is "since anything can happen, yes, functional style's limitations are too limiting, since you'll need to accomodate anything later".

Comment: @Pimgd, let us assume that the coffee interface has just 2 methods as mentioned in wiki.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the use of a Decorator is not needed and just plain wrong.

Each ingredient seems to add a fixed cost and can be added multiple times.

As such, since each ingredient seems to be fixed in size and meaning, we can use an enum to store the ingredient -> cost relationship.

```
enum CoffeeIngredient {
    SPRINKLES(0.5, "Sprinkles"),
    MILK(0.2, "Milk");

    private double price;
    private String description;
    CoffeeIngredient(double price, String description){
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
}
```

As for storing the applied ingredients... we can use a `Map<CoffeeIngredient, Integer>` to store the quantity. I think the order of ingredients is not important. If it is, we can just use a `List<CoffeeIngredient>`.

```
class Coffee {
    private EnumMap<CoffeeIngredient, Integer> ingredients;
    public final double BASE_PRICE = 1.0d;

    public Coffee(){
        ingredients = new EnumMap<>();
    }

    public double getPrice(){
        double price = BASE_PRICE;
        for(Map.Entry<CoffeeIngredient, Integer> entry : ingredients.entrySet()){
            price += entry.getKey().getPrice() * entry.getValue();
        }
        return price;
    }

    public String getIngredients(){
        String result = "Coffee";
        for(Map.Entry<CoffeeIngredient, Integer> entry : ingredients.entrySet()){
            result += ", "+entry.getValue()+"x " +entry.getKey().getDescription();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void addIngredient(CoffeeIngredient toAdd){
        if(map.containsKey(toAdd)){
            map.put(toAdd, map.get(toAdd)+1);
        } else {
            map.put(toAdd, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And done. No decorator needed. Decorators are for when you need to take regular objects (which may be complex!) and apply special operations to them. Your coffee is so simple that the main work IS keeping track of the ingredients, and using Decorators for this purpose is just plain wrong.

I mentioned that the order of ingredients might be important, in that case the `addIngredient` becomes simply `list.add(toAdd)` and listing ingredients and summing price simply become iteration with summing.

There's a few improvements that could be made in my example, such as using a StringBuilder, or perhaps functional style to sum the price. You could also argue that making `CoffeeIngredient` an enum is programming data into your application, and that you should use external resources. All these improvements could be made, but in the end, you do not need a decorator here.

Comment: Well, I agree that the coffee example on wiki describing the decorator pattern is simplistic and I also agree with you that to only calculate the cost for a simple coffee object,  we do not need the decorator pattern as shown in your code but the main intention of my question was to compare oop vs functional style when it comes down to the usage of the decorator pattern.

Comment: @AjayIyengar We asked many questions about the specification. We asked you to clarify where you wanted to go with this. You could not do so and insisted on getting this exact design and the use of functional code reviewed. I say that in this exact case, you should not use a decorator. If you want to review the use of functional/normal code for the decorator pattern, then either ask on Programmers stackexchange (but it might get closed as opinion based without too much detail) OR find a good example of the decorator pattern where it is actually needed.

Comment: @AjayIyengar This is all because here at Code Review, we don't just review the code on a few aspects, we review it on all aspects - if your question is about the correctness of a small part of code, but it turns out that the entire section of code can be removed by a built-in function, then a good review will point this out. I personally believe that this way of reviewing results in practical and useful code.

Comment: @Pigmd, the title and description that I mention does convey that :
1. I am trying to implement decorator pattern using Java 8 functional style and 
2. I am currently analyzing implementation of the decorator pattern where I have posted one functional style solution and an existing solution on wiki.

So I am not sure why the title, description, question don't give an idea about the specification, restriction and where I am headed with this.

Comment: @AjayIyengar I understand where you want to go with this question. But if you want to discuss the question in that manner, Programmers.stackexchange, which is all about software architecture, would be far better for you. As I said before, here we're more about making real code better for use in a real environment. Abstract discussions lead to opinionated answers.